# Why cin to float and integer behaves differently?

Tags: c++

I have a code to discard the string inputs and print the float inputs.

```
#include "Lab2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{

    int number; // or float type

    std::string trash;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> number;
        std::cout << "Number: " << number << "\n";
        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> trash;
            std::cout << "Trash: " << trash << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I input

```
a   b
```

The result is

```
Number: 0
Trash: a
```

However, if I convert the type of the variable 'number' into `float`, then under the same input, I have

```
Number: 0
Trash: b
```

Thus, if the type of 'number' is an integer the string "a" is still in the input buffer after `cin >> number`.
However if it is `float` type (`float number`) the string "a" is removed.
Why such things happen?

OS: M1mac

Compiler: clang version 13.0.0

Comment: "Why cin to float and integer behaves differently?"- Ehh, because they are two quite different data types?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. With gcc 12 I get "Number: 0 Trash: a", for the input "a b".

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure, but input failure should leave that input in the stream.  This could break error handling code as you've now cleared the next input from the stream.  If you wanted to tell the user that `"a"` is not a valid number you can't because you don't know now that `"a"` was entered.

Comment: Same here, can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/TM5nbEYhY, what is your compiler?

Comment: This might be a bug in your particular implementation of C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver What I don't understand is how it's able to unwind the buffer after a failure at all -- an `istreambuf_iterator` is single pass.   Is there already a SO question for that?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just answered my own question -- with input `. b` the output is `Number:  0 Trash: b`  So, it's simply not advancing past the first character that makes it ill-formed.

Comment: @Spencer `istream` uses `peak` to see the current input without advancing the input iterator.  If it is an invalid character input should end and the bad input should remain in the stream.  `.` is a valid character for a floating point number so if it see that it will read it in before proceeding to the next character.  `a` OTOH is not a vaild character in a float unless `0X` has already be read in so it should still be in the input buffer.  I can't reproduce the OPs issue though so not sure if this is actually happening or if they have something confused.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's essentially what's happening; wrapped around that, however, it's fetching a `std::num_get` and then calling the facet's `get`, passing in an `istreambuf_iterator` out of the stream's buffer.

Comment: OS: m1 mac,
Compiler: Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)